# How to redirect to a new page in jquery callback function

Tags: java, servlets, jquery

I am developing an application using jquery along with servlets.I have been using jquery theme roller for interface In my Login.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#dialog").dialog();
}); 
 </script>

  <script>
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#LoginForm").submit(function()
    {
     var username=$("#username").val();
     var password=$("#password").val();
     var datastring='username='+username+ '&password= '+password;

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:'Login',
   data: datastring
   error: function(){
            alert("Data Error"); 
        },
        success: function (data){
            window.location.replace("Items.jsp");
        }
     });
    });
});
  </script>

</head>
 <body style="font-size:62.5%;">
<div id="dialog" title="Login">
<form id="LoginForm" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username"></input><br></br>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="pwd"></input><br></br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" align="middle"></input>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

The data is being passed to the servlet and once the login is successful i want the user to be redirect to a new page say Items.jsp. In my callback I have used **window.location.replace("Items.jsp")**.I am not able to redirect.

I tried with **response.sendRedirect("Items.jsp")** and return **"Items.jsp" **

But am Not able to Redirect it to a new page.Where I am goin wrong..

Thanks:)

Comment: haveyou tried puting an alert inside success?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `window.location = "items.jsp"` ?

**EDIT**

I see you are missing a "url:" parameter in your ajax call.

Look at my example here which works.

http://jsfiddle.net/zuSZg/

Comment: @netbrain-yes I tried window.location..But I stay in the same page inspite of loggin in

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with the way you retrieve the redirect value and set it.

Comment: @netbrain...In my servlet I just check for authentication and then I want to redirect to new page on success...can it be done without callback by using response.sendRedirect in my servlet itself??

Comment: @netbrain-I deleted url while editing..Its included in my code

Comment: No it cant' you have to make the browser redirect with the main page.

Comment: @bumblebee hi, I m trying to do the same ...making a jquery Ajax call from login.jsp and calling the servlet. From the servlet however I wanted to redirect to welcome.sp but the welcome.jsp doesn't render. No errors either. Any help would be great!

Comment: Saw your comment now. So you can't redirect an Ajax call from the servlet to a new jsp. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Setting window.location to new URL will change the current webpage to the specified location.

```
window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.href ="Items.jsp"`

Source: [window.location MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: :) i saw your answer only after I edited my answer It was after reading MDC.
`window.location.href` should also work. I will revert my answer

Comment: @naveen...In my servlet I just check for authentication and then I want to redirect to new page on success...can it be done without callback by using response.sendRedirect in my servlet itself??     I pass the credentials in my servlet to the login method where checking is done and the user is directed to new page.Is call back necessary in this case?

Comment: @Sadhwika Chandramohan: its better to do the redirect on server. client side code can be easily manipulated. In your case we dont need an ajax call just post the form and redirect if credentials are good

Comment: @naveen.. Oh you mean to say that I can use the normal post method to pass the data to servlet and redirect to new page from servlket only...Thanks...Am a beginner to both java and jquery..thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this :
 $(window.location).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
```